# Arch linux ( kvm/qemu virtualization ) failed to open libiscsi.so.4

Tags: arch-linux, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

I have fallowed the steps from Arch Linux [#KVM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KVM) and [#qemu](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU)

1) `sudo pacman -S` then installed libs

```
libvirt
libiscsi 
libaio
qemu
qemu-arch-extra 
qemu-block-iscsi 
qemu-block-rbd 
qemu-block-gluster
```

2) `$ lscpu` check if VT-x is enabled

3) added the `.conf` file in the `/etc/modprobe.d/` for the fallowing modules:

```
network device (virtio-net)
block device (virtio-blk)
controller device (virtio-scsi)
serial device (virtio-serial)
balloon device (virtio-balloon)
```

4) I have included and run the `mkinitcpio.conf` the `modconf` hook to load the modules in initramfs.

5) run `$ lsinitcpio`

I think is an issues here because in the output i don't see any virtualization module loaded:

```
usr/lib/modules
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/modules.devname
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/modules.builtin.bin
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/modules.symbols.bin
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/modules.alias.bin
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/modules.dep.bin
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/sdhci.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/ext4.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/usb-common.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/ehci-pci.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/sd_mod.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/serio.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/cdrom.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/hid.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/ehci-hcd.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/sdhci-acpi.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/atkbd.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/xhci-pci.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/usbhid.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/xhci-hcd.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/sr_mod.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/crc16.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/rtsx_pci.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/libps2.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/libahci.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/led-class.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/scsi_mod.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/mmc_core.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/mmc_block.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/i8042.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/usbcore.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/ahci.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/libata.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/mbcache.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/usb-storage.ko
usr/lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/jbd2.ko
```

6) When I run :

`$ modinfo virtio-scsi` I get the fallowing answer :

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.5.4-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/scsi/virtio_scsi.ko.gz
license:        GPL
description:    Virtio SCSI HBA driver
alias:          virtio:d00000008v*
depends:        virtio,scsi_mod,virtio_ring
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.5.4-1-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload modversions
```

---

`$ systool -v -m virtio-scsi` and here for same module I get an error msg:

```
Error opening module `virtio-scsi`
```

---

7) And when I try to create a qemu image `$ qemu-img create -f raw arch-qemu 8G`
i get the fallowing error:

`$ Failed to open module:`libiscsi.so.4`: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: You have done a partial update: run `-Syyu` and make sure your mirror is up-to-date.

Comment: if I check the package files `pacman -Ql libiscsi`,  it appears a file `libiscsi /usr/lib/libiscsi.so.7` and I thing it has to do with the libiscsi installed version (v1.17.0-2).  
I try to build the libiscsi-1.4.0 but I get a lot of errors

Comment: @jasonwryan no results after update

Answer (score 1):

I manage to fix the issue after I installed manually an older version (`v1.14.0`) of libiscsi where qemu could find the `libiscsi.so.4` file.

First  I removed the `v1.17.0-2` installed with pacman 
`sudo pacman -Rddn libiscsi` without uninstalling the qemu-block-iscsi dependency.

I cloned the source code from github [sahlberg/libiscsi](https://github.com/sahlberg/libiscsi) and after the build I installed the library with libtool. I'm aware that this is not the best solution because on the next update of qemu i will have to remove my manual install and use the `pacman` package again.

For the moment I see that on the arch linux [qemu-page](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/qemu/) the package is :

> Flagged out-of-date on 2016-05-10 Version 2.6.0-1 in testing

code executed as root:

```
# git clone folder - libiscsi/

# Making install in lib
# directory 'libiscsi/lib'

 mkdir -p '/usr/lib'
 /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libiscsi.la '/usr/lib'

 libtool --finish /usr/lib

----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Libraries have been installed in: /usr/lib

----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Making install in utils
# directory 'libiscsi/utils'

 mkdir -p '/usr/bin'
 /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c iscsi-inq iscsi-ls iscsi-perf iscsi-readcapacity16 iscsi-swp '/usr/bin'

----------------------------------------------------------------------

# directory 'libiscsi/examples'

 mkdir -p '/usr/bin'
 install -c ld_iscsi.so '/usr/bin'

----------------------------------------------------------------------

# directory 'libiscsi/    

 mkdir -p '/usr/include/iscsi'
 install -c -m 644 include/iscsi.h include/scsi-lowlevel.h '/usr/include/iscsi'
 mkdir -p '/usr/lib/pkgconfig'
 install -c -m 644 libiscsi.pc '/usr/lib/pkgconfig'
```

I had run the commands manually because by default the `make install` from libiscsi was installing the lib in `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib`.

Any comments and suggestions are welcome!

Comment: solution : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=212654

Comment: That's waaaaay overcomplicating it and screwing up your package filesystem in the process. All you need to do is find the older version here and download its PKGBUILD: https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/log/trunk?h=packages/libiscsi